# Django-Select2 Heavy Widget

Tags: python, django, jquery-select2, django-select2

I was trying to implement Django-select2 for the first time.... I referred their [documentation](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django_select2.html#module-django_select2.forms) and some of the stack overflow solutions to implement it.... I managed to get ajax functionality work properly, also i am able to select multiple choices... however  when I submit and validate the form, I am getting error like -> "***Select a valid choice. 123456 is not one of the available choices.***"

I am not understanding what I am doing wrong....

**here is my form.**

```
class MyCustReqForm(forms.ModelForm):
    initial_customer = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            widget=HeavySelect2MultipleWidget(data_view='customer_ajax',
                                              attrs={'data-minimum-input-length': 4, 'delay':200},
                                              model=Customer),

    )
    end_customer = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            widget=HeavySelect2MultipleWidget(data_view='customer_ajax',
                                              attrs={'data-minimum-input-length': 4, 'delay':200},
                                              model=Customer),

    )

    class Meta:
        model = Workflow_Customer
        fields = [ 'initial_customer', 'end_customer' ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['initial_customer'].widget.attrs.update({'style': 'width:100%', 'data-placeholder': 'Select Customer'})
        self.fields['end_customer'].widget.attrs.update({'style':'width:100%', 'data-placeholder':'Select end customer'})
```

**and customer_ajax view calls below function...**

```
def customer_select2(request):
    term = request.GET.get("term", None)
    if term:
        res = list(Customer.objects.filter(Q(customer_number__contains=term) | Q(customer_name__contains=term)).values('id', 'customer_number', 'customer_name'))[:10]
    if res:
        result = [{'id': value['id'], 'text': value['customer_number'] + ' ' + value['customer_name'] } for index, value in enumerate(res)]

        return JsonResponse({'err': 'nil', 'results': result}, safe=False)

return JsonResponse(data={'success': False, 'errors': 'No mathing items found'})
```

when I checked in debug mode. I found that choices are empty... 
[image: screenshot of debug]

I appreciate for the quick help... if possible, please provide one complete example which explains how form defined and view used for Ajax function...

Answer (score 1):

That happens because when you send your form there aren't initial choices so the chosen option don't pass the validation. When you send your form, the class **MyCustReqForm** is initialized and in that moment you must do a requets to get choices of your form field. That choices must containt your chosen option. For example:

> self.fields['customer'].choices = call_to_end_point()

When the request is **'GET'** there isn't problem, but in the request **'POST'** is necessary to have some basic options.

PD: Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to write custom clean methods so this way you are defining your own validations for a field thus overriding django form validation for the choice field.

```
def clean_initial_customer(self):
  choices = self.cleaned_data["initial_customer"]
  # write your custom logics and remove any errors
```

let me know if you find some issue in implementing the same.